# Parse API Local Datastore - pinInBackground()

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I am attempting to use the Parse local datastore (from the [Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore) API) feature on Android and am having a problem at the very first step, I simply pasted the sample code:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);

gameScore.pinInBackground();
```

And Android studio gives the following error: **cannot find symbol method pinInBackground()**

As a second question, ultimately I would like to have an adapter available to use offline, i.e:

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "TestObject");
adapter.pinInBackground();
```

are the above two lines of code possible??

Comment: are you using SDK version 1.5.0?  and no, you can't pin the adapter.

Comment: Yes I am using SDK version 1.5.0
BTW, this code is in the onCreate method as per examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first Question: You have to set a SaveCallback()

```
    gameScore.pinInBackground( new SaveCallback( ) {

        @Override
        public void done( ParseException e ) {
            if( e == null ) {
                //success
            } else {
                //fail
            }
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Thank you that was it, I have looked at the docs but could you please give some more information on what the SaveCallback() does and why it is necessary?

Comment: It is not necessary, you can set null for the Callback like this: "gameScore.pinInBackground(null);". But in some cases you want to know when the data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

To your second Question:

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "TestObject");
adapter.pinInBackground();
```

No, it is not possible. Please read the documentation to understand how to works the ParseQueryAdapter. [Parse Android User Interface](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui)

Comment: all your answers have been very helpful!!

Comment: It is not obvious to me why it is not possible to use ParseQueryAdapter together with local datastore.

Comment: Misread the question. but, I am however getting 'Method not allowed' whenever I try to use a ParseQueryAdapter after enabling local datastore.

Comment: @cYrixmorten, please open a new question and explain your problem. When possible with code snippet. I need more content to "Methode not allowed". regards John

Comment: @John Was opening one just now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481314/parse-local-datastore-and-parsequeryadapter-causing-method-not-allowed-when-pinn