# Parse local datastore and ParseQueryAdapter causing Method not allowed when pinning is enabled

Tags: android, parse-platform

Just tried the new Local Datastore feature in my app and it kept crashing telling `Method not allowed when pinning is enabled`

Specifically it crashes as soon as I set the adapter `listView.setAdapter(mAdapter)`.

It took me some time to locate ParseQueryAdapter as the problem since the LogCat does not give much clues.

So is it not possible to use a ParseQueryAdapter together with having local datastore enabled?

The documentation have not mentioned otherwise, other than having queries with cache is not allowed.

The onCreateView of my fragment holding listview:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_circuit_select,
            container, false);

    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
    mAdapter = new SelectMyCircuitAdapter(getActivity(),
            new SelectedCallback() {

                @Override
                public void circuitSelected(Circuit circuit) {
                    mSelectedCircuit = circuit;
                    startButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter); // <- HERE
    return rootView;
}
```

The constructor of SelectMyCircuitAdapter:

```
public SelectMyCircuitAdapter(Context context,
        SelectedCallback circuitSelectedCallback) {
     super(context, Circuit.class);
    this.mCircuitSelectedCallback = circuitSelectedCallback;
}
```

And finally the LogCat:

```
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not allowed when Pinning is enabled.
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.parse.ParseQuery.checkPinningEnabled(ParseQuery.java:595)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.parse.ParseQuery.getCachePolicy(ParseQuery.java:620)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter$3.done(ParseQueryAdapter.java:351)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.parse.Parse$5$1.run(Parse.java:887)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-05 20:00:15.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1910):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is a bug.  We've created an internal task and this will be fixed with the next release.

Comment: Hey, didn't know you Parse guys monitored this tag so closely @Fosco :-)

Comment: @Fosco Cool, will look forward to it :)

Comment: @Fosco do you happen to have an ETA for the fix, or a place where it is possible to follow the progress?

Comment: I think a new version will be released with the fix in the next few days.

Comment: @Fosco any updates on the new version?

Comment: @Fosco indeed an update would be nice. Would really like to incorporate this into my next app update and not possible before release of the fix.

Comment: Sorry guys, the update is still in review.

Comment: @Fosco I don't suppose you have any updates on when 1.5.1 will be released?

Comment: +1 Waiting for any updates on this bug. Essential for my app.

Comment: i'm getting this error now with version 1.10. what do i do?

Comment: @Victor I will almost bet that it is not the same error, but that you cannot compile as ParseQueryAdapter is not found. They moved it to ParseUI, an external library that you must include. You can find it on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Parse Android Changelog**
>
> v1.5.1 — May 30, 2014
>
> Fixed various bugs with Local
>   Datastore.

I had a similar problem but it was fixed today with the release of the new Parse Android SDK version 1.5.1, you should check it out and try again.

Comment: Just a heads up to why I have not accepted the answer yet. Have a rather big refactoring task on my hands to confirm that the new update has fixed the bug. A simple switch gave other errors, which most likely makes sense due to false assumption on data being present and the like. Will get back as soon as I have managed to do the full refactor, finally have the time to dive into it and will be excited if it actually works :) cheers

Comment: Despite having some issues with SaveEventually using Local Datastore, this answer is accepted as 1.5.1 indeed made it possible to use the local data together with ParseQueryAdapter